# Как обратится через класс к div?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="line number1 index0 alt2"></div>
  <div class="line number2 index1 alt1"></div>
</div>
```

> Я хочу чтоб все div которые под классом container были цветом черным как я могу обратится используя только класс container?

Comment: .container { background-color: black }

Comment: напиши ответ чтоб я тебя выбрал как за лучший

Comment: в данном случае для людей из гугла это не будет иметь пользы я думаю, так что можно и не назначать меня лучшим :)

Comment: @PavelGrishaev Нет, мы хотим назначить Вас лучшим.

Comment: @Igor назначай !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/*Абсолютно все <div>, которые находятся в .container*/
.container div {
  background-color: black;
}

/*Только на первом уровне вложенности*/
.container > div {
  background-color: black;
}
```